# Explanation of the scatter method in python (for machine learning)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm brand new to python and machine learning, and as part of my course at university we're using numpy, matplotlib, and sci-kit learn. Ok so I have a question. The code below works perfectly fine, my issue is that I don't really understand what's happening. So for this one:

```
%matplotlib inline
X=iris.data
Y=iris.target
#first two features are sepal length and sepal width
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=Y, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
plt.xlabel('Sepal length')
plt.ylabel('Sepal width')
```

I tried to check the documentation but it didn't really make any sense to me.
  Here I would like to know what the arguments in plt.scatter() mean. I don't really understand it, what does c=Y mean, what is cmap why are there two X coordinates?

As for this next code:

```
%matplotlib inline

#here's also how to plot in 3d:
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D #

#create a new figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))


#this creates a 1x1 grid (just one figure), and now we are plotting
#subfigure 1 (this is what 111 means)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d') 

#plot first three features in a 3d Plot.  Using : means that we take all    
#elements in the correspond array dimension
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2],c=Y)
```

What I want to know here is:

fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d'). This third 1 doesn't really make sense to me. I understand the 1x1 grid, but I don't understand "and now we are plotting subfigure 1".

Also:

The ax.scatter() arguments make no sense here either. Why is the format different than the one above? Why are there three X's and no cmap? I don't really understand it. Why do they not use plt.scatter()?

Comment: `X` is a variable, not the name of the argument. It is an array with at least three columns. The first is used as the x-variable of the plot. The second column is used as the y-variable of the plot. The third column is used to scale the size of the markers. the colors of the markers are set from data assigned to the `Y` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets go step by step through your questions.

First, *"why are there two X coordinates?"*: The `scatter` function (http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) takes `x` and `y` coordinates for the markers; in this case both the `x` and `y` coordinates are stored in one single 2D array called `X`: `X[:,0]` are simply the `x` coordinates, and `X[:,1]` the `y` coordinates. *"what does c=Y mean?"*: There are several options for colouring the markers:

> c can be a single color format string, or a sequence of color specifications of length N, or a sequence of N numbers to be mapped to colors using the cmap and norm specified via kwargs (see below). Note that c should not be a single numeric RGB or RGBA sequence because that is indistinguishable from an array of values to be colormapped. c can be a 2-D array in which the rows are RGB or RGBA, however, including the case of a single row to specify the same color for all points.

So in this case, the relevant part seems to be *"N numbers to be mapped to colors using the cmap"*, i.e. you provide data values, and `scatter` colours the markers using some color map (http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html).

*"fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d'). This third 1 doesn't really make sense to me."*: The `add_subplot` adds sub plots on a grid, where `111` (or lets use `322` as a more clear example) means a grid with 3 rows, 2 columns, and you are using the second position on the grid (i.e. row 0, column 1) as the current subplot. So `subplot(111)` simply means a figure with 1 row and 1 column of sub plots, and you are using (what a surprise..) the first and only position.

*"Why are there three X's and no cmap?"*: You first imported `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d` and next specified `projection='3d'` to `add_subplot`, so you are now creating a 3D `scatter` plot, which requires the specification of `x`, `y` and `z` coordinates of the markers.

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=Y, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
```

is a two dimensional plot with the color `c=Y` indicating which flower the (x,y)-->(X[:,0],X[:,1]) coordinate point belong to. [Describes the scatter function in detail.](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) The `cmap` argument `plt.cm.Paired` means the colormap is using the entire range of colors available. If you are not using float data then this argument is superfluous; what happens when you plot without it?

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
```

111, here refers to the first element in a 1x1 array of plots; this doesn't seem very useful here but becomes useful as you create plots with multiple subplots.

```
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2],c=Y)
```

Here you are plotting a 3-dimensional plot of attributes (x,y,z) --> (X[:,0],X[:,1],X[:,2]) while Y is again assigning colors to the points based on their true class.